# Sorting files (images) and then renaming them automatically according to the sort

Tags: windows, rename, sorting, ordering

We want to sort image files in a directory and want them to renamed according to the order we gave.

Is there a tool that can do this?

(os: windows xp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it:

1. Open the folder containing the files
2. Next select all the files you want to rename
3. Then select File from the top of the browser and, click Rename.
4. Type the new name, and then press ENTER.

First file will be named NewFileName and the rest will be renamed in the following sequence NewFileName (1), NewFileName  (2), etc.

Works in both xp and vista...

Answer (score 3):

Use the free [Bulk File Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/).

Answer (score 2):

The [**AmoK Exif Sorter**](http://www.amok.am/en/freeware/amok_exif_sorter/) might be more flexible for image files.
I described it earlier at [**How to sort images into folders, based on resolution?**](https://superuser.com/questions/17562/how-to-sort-images-into-folders-based-on-resolution/17573#17573)
<sub>(that's the first **related** question on the right here...)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For renaming files - and moving them to new folders -with the folders using names you defined, you can't get better than PFrank - http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/

Probably the most powerful file renamer there is, and it's free, a little learning curve needed as it uses regular expressions/regex but will do just about any batch file rename, re-org that you want!